Getting validation state false error from nullable list
I'm trying to fill a list of integer numbers named "sizeQuantities" from a list of inputs of  my view. the "ModelState.IsValid" is for checking validation of the inputs. And, when I leave one of this inputs empty, the "ModelState" returns false. So, how can I get this list without false. I put this list nullable but I get false again.

this is the code behind:
    public IActionResult OnPost(IFormFile? imgProductUp, List<int>? selectedSizes, List<int>? sizeQuantities)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        int productId = _productService.AddProduct(Product, imgProductUp);
        _productService.AddSizeToProductByAdmin(productId, selectedSizes, sizeQuantities);
        return RedirectToPage("Index");

this is the view:
     <div class="form-group">
         <label>Sizes</label>
         <hr />
         @{
             List<Size>? sizes = ViewData["Sizes"] as List<Size>;
         }
         @if (sizes != null)
         {
             @foreach (Size size in sizes)
             {
                 <div style="margin-top:5px;">
                     <input type="checkbox" name="selectedSizes" value="@size.SizeId" /> @size.SizeName
                     <div>
                         <label>تعداد</label>
                         <input type="number" name="sizeQuantities" class="form-control" /> 
                     </div>
                     <hr />
                 </div>
             }
         }
     </div>

this the picture of output enter image description here.

After debugging the code and you would see that the ModelState is invalid with multiple same error message The value " is invalid, and the messages' count depend on how many nullable value you pass of the sizeQuantities.

What you did(List<int>?) is make sizeQuantities nullable but the item in sizeQuantities variable cannot be nullable(must be int type).
Change List<int>? sizeQuantities to List<int?>? sizeQuantities:
public IActionResult OnPost(IFormFile? imgProductUp, List<int>? selectedSizes, List<int?>? sizeQuantities)

